# How do I get the behaviour of the 'Insert' key on VIM using a Macbook Pro without an insert key?

Tags: macos, vim

Because the apple store couldn't help me, and indeed had never seen VIM before, despite the fact it comes installed as standard on OSX ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surely you can just do a simple:

```
inoremap <C-l> <Insert>
```

I can't say I've ever had to use replace mode enough that `<Esc>R` wasn't quick enough for me.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the <Esc>R shortcut- that's good enough for me!

Answer (score 11):

With iTerm or [iTerm2](http://code.google.com/p/iterm2/) you can map an unused key to insert. For example, I've mapped F19 to "send escape sequence" `[2~` (that's the xterm escape sequence for the insert key).

In iTerm2, go to preferences, "Bookmarks", select the "Keyboard" tab, click the "+", press the key you want to map, select action "send escape sequence" and then enter `[2~`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `i` instead of insert.

Comment: in Linux it works.. but i haven't tested it on Mac.

Comment: That's not the equivalent action, I'm afraid. The insert key toggles between insert and replace.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key):

**Toggling insert mode**

Press Ctrl-Space to start and to stop insert mode (the same suggestion using Shift-Space is above):

> nnoremap  i imap

Or you may prefer to map Ctrl-Space to a rather than i so that repeatedly pressing Ctrl-Space does not move the cursor back (remember that pressing I allows you to insert a character at the beginning of the line):

> nnoremap  a imap

You would put this in your .vimrc so it happens on start-up.

Answer (score 1):

Either use Mac's [onscreen keyboard](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/reference/onscreenkeyboard.html) or use a hotkey program to rebind one of your existing keys to Insert. One Superuser thread provides several [Autohotkey equivalents for Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/28023/autohotkey-equivalent-on-mac) such as [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/).